# Using operator sealed with the members of the class

Tags: c#

I've found in the Troelsen's book, that operator **sealed** can be used on the members of the class to protect **virtual** methods from the **override**.

But if I don't want to **override** a **virtual** methods, what sense to make it **virtual**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a situation like this:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void MyMethod()
    {
        //...
    }
}


public class B : A
{
    public override void MyMethod()
    {
        //...
    }
}


public class C : B
{
    public override void MyMethod()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

But what if you want for the inheriting class `C` NOT to be able to override `B`'s `MyMethod`, while still allowing `B` to override `A`'s? Then you can do:

```
public class B : A
{
    public sealed override void MyMethod()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

With this change made, you can no longer override the method in `C`.

Comment: Do not quite understand. Classes **B** and **C** have their own copies of the method. So if **C** will inherit **B** (without using sealed), then method in **B** didn't changed, because it have it's own copy. Or not?

Comment: @dima I'm afraid I don't understand your question. The method in `B` *overrides* the one in `A`, and the method in `C` (without sealed) overrides the ones in both `A` and `B`. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I've not noticed that **C** inherit **B**, I thought, that it inherit **A**, now it's all clear.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, consider the following example:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void SomeMethod() { }
}

public class B : A
{
    public sealed override void SomeMethod() { }
}

public class C : B
{
    public override void SomeMethod() { }
}
```

In this example, without the use of the `sealed` keyword on `SomeMethod` in `class B`, `class C` would be able to override it because it's original declaration was as `virtual`. The `sealed` keyword in this context generates a compiler error. See the [MSDN for more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx).